# How to set up NAT46 on Linux router?

Tags: linux, router, routing, ipv6, nat

I have a internet connection supporting IPv6 only. But some of my devices (like an AV-receiver) are only capable of IPv4.

```
                      ______________
                     | Linux router |
                     |--------------|
                     |              |
internet     <-->    | eth0: init6  |    <-->    PCs, etc. (IPv6)
(all IPv6)           |              |
                     | eth1: init   |    <-->    e. g. AV-receiver (IPv4)
                     |______________|
```

How to set up the linux router to offer internet for my old hardware like AV-receiver, too?

I would try it with `nat64` device via [Tayga](http://www.litech.org/tayga/). But how do the route and the `ip[6]tables` commands look like?

```
ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev nat64    # outgoing
???                                 # incoming
```

Comment: If your connection is IPv6 only, how do you access IPv4 content? NAT64 from your ISP?

Comment: I think so. In combination with DNS64 it's completely out of my awareness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an IPv6 only connection with NAT64 and DNS64 then you need a 464xlat implementation to provide IPv4 to applications and devices that don't support IPv6. You can find a Linux implementation here: https://github.com/toreanderson/clatd